# Does a conditional pointer-events attribute exist?

Tags: html, css

I have an overlaying (i.e. higher z-index value) div element that, when hovered, triggers the movement of multiple p elements underneath it. This unfortunately means that the content of these p elements, due to the lower z-index value, cannot be selected, which is a necessity. Of course the solution in this case would usually be to give the overlaying div an attribute of pointer-events:none, although in this case such an attribute would prevent the hover effect.

How can I work around this issue?

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/vrq1bnqe/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#hovdetect {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}

.contact {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 1;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 2vw;
  font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', serif;
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 125%;
}

.contact::selection {
  background: #808080;
}

#email {
  left: auto;
  right: 2vw;
  visibility: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 20vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFFFFF url('img/head.png')center/auto 60% no-repeat;
}

#hovdetect:hover~#header {
  background-position: 2%50%;
  background-size: auto 18%;
}

#hovdetect:hover~#email {
  width: 1;
  left: 2vw;
  right: auto;
  top: 15vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='hovdetect'></div>
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='navbar'>
</div>
<div class='contact'>
  <p><i class='fa fa-phone' aria-hidden='true'></i> [redacted]</p>
</div>
<div id='email' class='contact'>
  <p>[redacted] <i class='fa fa-keyboard-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddler to replicate your issue so others do not wrongfully assume your html and css?

Comment: ...you could do it the other way around; that is.. use the trigger button with a lower z-index and apply pointer-events:none to the multiple p elements until their animation is complete..